# Repairing Dynamics CRM 2011 Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, crm, microsoft-dynamics-crm

As stated above, I had a bit of an issue with my CRM 2011 server last week. I run a small computer repair company and use it to manage my clients. I was running the server in a VirtualBox VM and the host hard drive ran out of space. My original problem was that the virtual hard drive got corrupted towards the end. I was able to use Acronis to clone the VHD to a new one and got my Server 2008 R2 running again. Then I ran into a problem where SQL Server 2008 wasn't running correctly. Ran a repair on that and got access to my data again. When I went to log into my CRM, all of the dashboards threw a generic SQL error. I found a script on another blog that helped me fix that issue(script below). But now whenever I try to open any entity, I get a generic error. No information on whats going on and no error codes. I can see the specific entries in the list view, but the error comes up every time I try to open one of them. I tried repairing CRM multiple times with no change. Any help?

```
EXEC sp_resetstatus 'MicrosoftCRM_MSCRM';
ALTER DATABASE MicrosoftCRM_MSCRM SET EMERGENCY

DBCC checkdb('MicrosoftCRM_MSCRM')
ALTER DATABASE MicrosoftCRM_MSCRM SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

DBCC CheckDB ('MicrosoftCRM_MSCRM', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
ALTER DATABASE MicrosoftCRM_MSCRM SET MULTI_USER
```

Edit. Link to Trace: http://www.onyx-computers.com/crmtrace.log

Trace was too big for the post so I added it to my FileSonic account.

I should also add that yesterday, I tried creating a new server from scratch and importing organizations database. That didnt help at all. It still does the same thing. I also noticed that when the error page comes up, there is a Try Again and Cancel button and when I click Try Again a few times, I get a 404 error.

Edit. Changed link from FileSonic to my web host.

Comment: The problem with that script, is that it can be destructive, see the line with "REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS". It may have brought your database online, but with missing information.

Answer (score 0):

The first step to solve you problem, is to enable the tracing on your CRM server. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490.

The trace files should contain more information about the error (please post them here).